# jQuery auto Page scroll on mousemove

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var y = e.clientY;
    var h = $(window).height();
    var n = h - y;  
    if (n < 60) {
        var t = parseFloat($(window).scrollTop());
        console.log(t);
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:t + 60 + 'px'},200);
    } else {
        $('html,body').stop();
    }
});
```

I am using above code for page scroll when mouse moving to bottom(< 60px) based on mouse Y value. every time I need to move mouse up above 60 for getting page scrolling.  Is it possible to make this scroll more smoothly like easing effect.  [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/twp1LgcL/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery alone support only `swing` and `linar` easing. You should add jQuery UI to add support for more complex easing functions.

Anyway, I suggest you to use a more perfomant and compact library for easing, like Velocity.js (http://julian.com/research/velocity/)